# Iterate over keys of association

Tags: associations

How do you iterate over the keys or rules of an association (in any order)? E.g. for

```
<|"0"->"a", "1"->"b", "2"->"c"|>
```

I would like to either iterate over `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"` or tuples containing each key and value.

For example, something that performed the equivalent of a python dictionary's `items`, method would be ideal (which returns a list (or iterator) in the form `[(key1, value1), ...]`, so `{{"0", "a"}, {"1", "b"}, {"2", "c"}}` here).

Comment: Simply use `Map`, `KeyValueMap` or `KeyMap`?

Comment: Can you tell what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Woooops! Done! :)

Comment: @SLesslyTall You see, you want `KeyValueMap[List] @ asso` but who could've known :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To iterate over the keys of an association, first get the keys in a list using [`Keys`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys.html). then use this in your favorite iteration construct ([`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html), [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), [`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html), [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), etc):

```
In[16]:= assoc = <|"0" -> 0, "1" -> 1, "2" -> 2|>;

In[17]:= Do[Print[x], {x, Keys[assoc]}]

During evaluation of In[17]:= 0

During evaluation of In[17]:= 1

During evaluation of In[17]:= 2
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to map over the keys to transform them into something else, you can use `KeyMap`:

```
a = <|"0" -> 0, "1" -> 1, "2" -> 2|>;
a // KeyMap[("newKey" <> #) &]
(* <|"newKey0" -> 0, "newKey1" -> 1, "newKey2" -> 2|> *)
```

Otherwise, the good old `Map` will iterate over the values as if the structure were a list:

```
a // Map[("newVal" <> ToString@#) &]
(* <|"0" -> "newVal0", "1" -> "newVal1", "2" -> "newVal2"|> *)
```

You should also look up `KeyValueMap` to see if that would make your task easier.

*Edit*

Henrik Schumacher's succinct comment contains everything I have elaborated here. His comment had not been posted when I began writing this answer.